# Как средствами java создать xml таблицу?

Tags: xml, java

Здравствуйте!

Есть задача: "Создать XML документ с расписанием..." 
Не понятно как должен выглядеть xml документ чтобы он содержал расписание.

Пишу на java, пока добился:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<R>
<tt>
<t>101</t>
<t>11</t>
<s>HF</s>
<s>Ao</s>
</tt>
</R>
```

Может его открыть как-то по особому надо? 
Пока этот код выводит всё в строчку(

Comment: Можно по подробней. Что конкретно нужно? Что значит "Не понятно как должен выглядеть xml документ чтобы он содержал расписание"? XML файл, это просто текстовый файл. Можно просто взять StringBuilder, напихать туда строк и вывести в текстовый файл с расширением xml. Конечно, если \\n в конце строк не ставить, то весь файл будет в строчку. Вот так просто и средствами одной лишь джавы. А если вопрос состоит в том, что не понятно какие тэги писать в xml файл, так тут сам программист решает какие тэги нужны. Нужно только конвенции соблюдать, чтоб можно было этот файл прочитать другим xml парсером.

Comment: Спасибо, вроде разобрался за 5 часов что это и как выглядит) Я создал xml, появилась проблема создать DTD. Мега вопрос: как проверить, каким приложением, что DTD верно описывает файл или что файл правильный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот на SO [хороший ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699620/how-to-validate-xml-with-dtd-using-java). По сути просто отпарсить xml файл и проверить наличие ошибок. Как оформить DTD файл можно посмотреть [тут](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd.asp).